# what causes the segmentation fault?

Tags: c, pointers

I create a segmentation fault in the recursive loop, but dont understand why. Could anybody help me?

```
struct node{
int value;
    int order;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
};

typedef struct node node_t;

node_t array[10];

void createTree(node_t **p, int order){
   (*p)->value = rand()%10;
   (*p)->order = order;
   printf("%i", (*p)->value);
   printf(" ");
   printf("%i\n", (*p)->order);

   if (!order){
       (*p)->left = NULL;
       (*p)->right = NULL;
       return; 
   }
//I believe that here is the origin of the problem...     
createTree(&(*p)->left, order-1);
createTree(&(*p)->right, order-1);
}

int main(void)
{
node_t *root = &array[0];
srand(time(NULL));
createTree(&root, 1);
printf("%i\n", root->value);
return 1;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried with gdb or similar?

Comment: no, I am very little experienced with debugging - sadly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is

```
node_t array[10];
```

you are creating 10 nodes and since this array is declared in file scope (global) it is zero-initialized and thus value of `right` and `left` pointers will be `NULL`.

Now

```
createTree(&(*p)->left, order-1);
```

in this you are passing the address of left node.

In this statement

```
(*p)->value = rand()%10;
```

`*p` is `NULL` and dereferencing `NULL` yields segmentation fault.

Comment: No such thing as *global scope*; the proper C terminology is *file scope*.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you ever set the `left` and `right` members. You set them to `NULL` if `order` is zero but otherwise you don't set them at all. And yet you pass the address of these members recursively as parameters. Obviously, such an address is invalid to access, which your code does.

How did you expect that to work?